# Python: constructing a 2 dimensional array

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to create my first 2 dimensional arrary. But I'm not getting the anticipated results:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[11,12,13],[21.22,23],[31,32,33]] # nested list
x = np.array(a)  # cast into an array
x
```

My Results:

```
array([list([11, 12, 13]), list([21.22, 23]), list([31, 32, 33])],
      dtype=object)
```

I'm expecting x.ndim to return 2 since it's a List containing 3 other Lists, but it's only returning 1.

```
x.ndim
```

My Results:

```
1
```

I'm expecting x.shape to return (3,3,), but instead it's returning (3,)

```
x.shape
```

My Results:

```
(3,)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Isn't the issue a typo with `21.23` and wanted to create `21,23` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a typo in the second list element. Corrected:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33]] # nested list
>>> x = np.asarray(a)  # cast into an array
>>> print(x)
[[11 12 13]
 [21 22 23]
 [31 32 33]]
>>> x.shape
(3, 3)
>>>
```

Comment: This returns shape of (3,)